# RDLC report table split to left

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I'm trying to display my table in .rdlc like this

(col1)                   (col1) 

  1.                                 6.

  2.                                             7. 

  3.                                             8.

  4.                                             9.

  5.                                          10.

Is it doable?

(please also help me with my title to be easier to understand)

Comment: Yes it is very much doable. Is the number of rows always 10 or is it variable. If it is 20 would you divide into 10 and 10. What happens if the total rows span multiple pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 10 rows of data. You can create two tablix side by side and filter the data in each of them based on rowNumber 1-5 and 5-10.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255249.aspx

Comment: I can now limit my table rows to what i want(a half).Thanks for your answer. But still cant figure out how to display the rest part of it.

Comment: Can you please explain "how to display the rest part of it."?